# javascriptで配列の数を制限したい

Tags: javascript

配列の先頭に値を追加していくプログラムがあります。

これはどんどん増えていくので数を10個に制限したいのですが、やり方がわかりません。

どうしたらよいのでしょうか。

```
a = [1]
a.unshift(2) // [2, 1]
...
a.unshift(10) // [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
a.unshift(11) // [11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
```

`unshift()`の直後に配列を10個取り出して自己代入できればよいのですが、、、

Comment: これはどのような場面で使われるかを追記することは可能ですか？それともこれは単に Javascript の練習でしょうか。  

質問の内容からすると、実は [リングバッファ](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%83%90%E3%83%83%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1) が必要としているもののように見えます。  

そうであれば、関数の実装が同じになるにしても持たせるインタフェースが少し変わってきますし、コードを読む他の人の助けにもなると思います。

Answer (score 2):

下記の[`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)でのやり方はいかがでしょうか？

```js
function addLimited(array, value, limit) {
  array.unshift(value);
  array.splice(limit);
}

var array = [];

addLimited(array, 1, 10);
addLimited(array, 2, 10);
addLimited(array, 3, 10);
addLimited(array, 4, 10);
addLimited(array, 5, 10);
addLimited(array, 6, 10);
addLimited(array, 7, 10);
addLimited(array, 8, 10);
addLimited(array, 9, 10);
addLimited(array, 10, 10);
addLimited(array, 11, 10);

console.log(array); // [11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

少し強引ですが、unshiftを書き換えることで実現することもできます。

```
// 配列を拡張したtenAryオブジェクトを作成
var tenAry = {};
tenAry.__proto__ = [];
tenAry._unshift = tenAry.unshift
tenAry.unshift = function(v){
    this._unshift(v);
    this.splice(10);
}

// 20回unshiftする
for(var i=0; i<20; i++){
  tenAry.unshift(i);
}

console.log(tenAry); // -> [19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10]
```

`new Array()`するような感覚で実装したい場合は以下のようにすると良いです。

```
// TenArrayクラスのようなものを作成
function TenArray(){}
TenArray.prototype.__proto__ = []
TenArray.prototype.unshift = function(v){
    this.__proto__.__proto__.unshift.call(this, v);
    this.splice(10);
};

// 通常の配列を作成
var ary = new Array();

// unshiftで最大素数数が10個に制限されている配列を作成
var tenAry = new TenArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

a.lengthを、制限したい数に変更します。

```
var a= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];
a.length= 10; // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

a.unshift(12); // [12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
a.length= 10; // [12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

var a=[];
a.length= 10; // [undefined × 10]
```